# How to get email id of logged in user in Yii?

Tags: yii, gmail, social-networking, linkedin-api, yii-extensions

I am implementing login through social networks in my Yii site. I am using gmail, linkedin, twitter and facebook. I need to get the email of the users who are logging in to my site using these networks. I am able to get the email of the facebook user. But not the other networks. How can I get it ?

Comment: Read their documentation, I'm fairly certain you will be able to get some sort of unique identifier since virtually every action you would be able to do in the APIs would require this

Comment: There are a couple of extensions for this, they may answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Yii specific question (imo) but for the legacy of actually searching, people might end up on this post, looking for a Yii solution:

You should have a look at the [yii-eoauth](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eoauth) extention.
You will need to do the handshakes first to authenticate the users and afterwards you will be able to get the required details.

- [oAuth for Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/)
- [oAuth for twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq)
- [oAuth for Google](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2)
- [oAuth for Linked In](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-oauth-token)

Comment: That extension doesn't work with oAuth2 - and oAuth1 is deprecated for Google services - Sorry Googler, try another extension. If you find one, please comment here because I can't.

Comment: Yes, I did. I also tried the extensions that result gave. I'm not in china. The other extensions didn't work - I rolled my own.